# what am i doing wrong in these php scripts?

Tags: php, include

Here is config.php

```
<?php
define("DB_SERVER","localhost");
define("DB_NAME","photo_galley");
define("DB_USER_NAME","root");
define("DB_PASSWORD","");
echo DB_SERVER."config file<br>";
?>
```

Here is classes.php

```
<?php
    var_dump(include_once("config.php"));
    echo DB_SERVER."class file<br/>";
?>
<?php
    class MySQLDatabase{...
```

and here comes third file temp.php

```
<?php
    include_once("includes/classes.php");
    echo DB_SERVER." tem.php <br/>";
?>
```

both classes.php and config.php are in includes folder, includes folder is in photo_gallery folder , temp.php is in photo_gallery folder
how it looks like when i open classes.php in browser.
[image]

it shows thing as i thought. First show DB_SERVER value from config.php file then from classes.php file
But when i include classes.php file in any other file like in temp.php as shown in third piece of code it gives something that i didn't understand
here is it
[image]

I didn't understand output.
I think it's output should be same as that of classes.php with one more line showing DB_SERVER value from temp.php.

**Would you please tell me why these constants are shown as undefined when i open temp.php in browser? 

if include function in line is successful as shown by int(1) then why not it show DB_SERVER value from config.php?**

Answer (score 1):

In `temp.php` your `config.php` file path is wrong. Thats why you got the undefined constant.

`config.php` file inside the **includes** directory. But your temp.php file outside the includes directory.

in classes.php, You can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` add full path in such way you can access the same in all files.

Answer (score 1):

You include config.php from wrong location in `temp.php`. Remove the path. Also you should use `require_once` rather than `include_once` as config.php is crucial, so lack of it should stop the script.

Answer (score 1):

When you include classes.php relative path to config.php is includes/config.php.

```
<?php
include_once("includes/config.php");

class MySQLDatabase{...
```

Comment: `includes/config.php` is NOT **absolute** path

Answer (score 1):

Your scripts are fine. You just have a problem with your server configuration.

They're working correctly in mine:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

so we can say that when we use require include function it just copies code from file mentioned to file from which this function called. so when i call config from classes file it works fine. But when i call classes from temp it just copies code from there but for temp file  config file location is different so it doesn't work. Am i correct Mr. Developers...